# Difference between $n$-th partial sums of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}(\left[-\pi, \pi\right])$ and let $$S_n(f, x) = \sum_{h= -n}^n \widehat{f}(h) e^{ihx}.$$
Moreover, let $g(t):= f(x+t) - f(x)$. It is true that
$$ S_n(f, x) - S_n(g, 0) = f(x)?$$
Could anyone help me with the proof?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\widehat{f}(h)$ ? Making sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: $\widehat{f}(h)$ denotes the fourier transform of $f$, i.e. $$ S_n(f, x) = \sum_{h = -n}^n \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{ih(x-t)} dt.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$S_n(g,t)  = -f(x) + \sum_{h=-n}^n \hat{f}(h)e^{ihx}e^{iht}$$

from the Fourier translation property. This immediately leads to

$$S_n(f,x)-S_n(g,0) = f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\widehat{g}(h)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x+t)-f(t))e^{-i ht}dt=\frac{e^{ihx}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi+x}f(u)e^{-ihu}du-\widehat{f}(h)=(e^{ihx}-1)\widehat{f}(h)$$
because $u\mapsto f(u)e^{-ihu}$ is $2\pi$-peridoc. Thus
$$ S_n(g,0)=\sum_{h=-n}^n\widehat{f}(h)(e^{ihx}-1)=S_n(f,x)-S_n(f,0) $$
But we don't have $S_n(f,0)=f(x).$